# SAP Commerce Cloud (Hybris) - Search for Customers in ASM by Groups (B2B Unit)

Tags: search, e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

My stakeholders would like our sales team to be able to look up customers in SAP Commerce Cloud (Hybris) Assisted Service Module using by entering the B2B Unit ID that the customer is linked to. In our implementation, B2B Units are linked to B2B Customers via the "Groups" field on the B2B Customer.

We know that it is possible to run this query in HAC using a Flexible Search Query, but I haven't found any evidence online that anyone has implemented something like this for the ASM User Search.

We currently have to create fake B2B Customers that contain the B2B Unit ID in the email address to facilitate this. This is not an ideal solution.

Apologies if I post this question in the wrong place - this is my first post here. I usually just browse.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend **DefaultAssistedServiceFacade** to add a feature for searching B2BUnit. Check **getSuggestedCustomerData** method.